# Legality of Apple Private SDK (app store aside)

Tags: ios, iphone

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find the exact thing.

**Bottom Line**
Is it legal to use Apple's private SDK for an app that is NOT distributed through the app store?

**Context**
I develop an app for Android that uses indoor location tracking, and the only way to use this functionality on iPhone is through private API. However, our app is used only within one building and therefore not distributed by Google Play and wouldn't be distributed using the App Store if possible. I assume the iPhones would have to be jailbroken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the legality of using private APIs. Talk to a lawyer about that.

The only thing I can say is that you don't have to jailbreak iPhone's to use private APIs.